# upload file with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a test which uploads a file with Selenium web driver using Java.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://favicon-generator.org/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("favicon")));
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("favicon"));
el.sendKeys("test.jpg");
```

After I run this the input field is not populated.

Comment: and when you click Create Favicon button, it says "You didn't select a image to upload. Please try again." ?

Comment: Yes. "You didn't select a image to upload. Please try again."

Comment: Provide full system path of the image

Comment: I tried, it does not help.

Comment: I tried also: el.sendKeys("c:/Users/Jacob/workspace/seleniumTest/test.jpg");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. The problem was the formatting of absolute path to the file. It should be:

```
el.sendKeys("c:\\Users\\Jacob\\workspace\\seleniumTest\\test.jpg");
```

Comment: Yes. I was about to post my answer. Glad you found it on your own!